# Draw on screen using mouse in assembly (emu8086)

Tags: assembly, mouse, pixel, emu8086

The code below lets you draw on screen with mouse, and works perfect. My problem is why does `CX` need to be divided by 2? Why is it doubled in the first place?

```
code segment
main proc far

mov al, 12h
mov ah, 0   ; set graphics video mode.
int 10h   

mov ax, 1   ;shows mouse cursor
int 33h

Next:
mov ax, 3   ;get cursor positon in cx,dx
int 33h

call putpix ;call procedure 
jmp Next

mov ah,4ch
int 21h
main endp

;procedure to print
putpix proc   
mov al, 7   ;color of pixel  
mov ah, 0ch    
shr cx,1    ; cx will get double so we divide it by two
int 10h     ; set pixel.
ret
putpix endp
code ends
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Next screenshot of emu8086 and your code will help us to understand what is going on:

- The purple arrow shows video mode 12h, which is 640x480.
- The blue arrow shows where the cursor is when the code gets the cursor position in (CX, DX). It's the lower right corner, I chose it on purpose to get the maximum values.
- I added a "readkey" code snippet to stop the execution in this point and see the values for CX and DX (the yellow bar).
- The red arrow shows the values for CX and DX. DX is 01DB = 475, which is in the range of 0..479. But CX is 04FA = 1274 (green arrow), which is impossible because the video mode allows columns in the range 0..639.
- The conclusion is simple: the mouse interrupt 33h returns a doubled value for the cursor column. In order to work around this emu8086-bug, the way to solve this is to divide the column by 2 (`shr cx, 1`).

[image]

Comment: So, it always returns a double value ?

Comment: @Asnira, yes, I tested different positions and it always returns doubled values for CX only.

Answer (score 2):

It looks you've encountered a bug in your emulator (or its mouse driver). When I run your program on DOSBox and under MS-DOS 6.22 running both under VirtualBox and directly on a PC, your program only draws pixels on the left hand side of the display.

[image: DOSBox screenshot]
[image: MS-DOS 6.22 under VirtualBox screenshot]

You might want to file a bug report with the people who wrote your emulator.

Comment: Its sad that EMU8086 is full of bugs.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way to fix the emu8086-bug mentioned in Jose Manuel Abarca Rodríguez's answer, is to use this graphics mode:

```
mov ah, 00
mov al, 13h       ; set screen to 256 colors, 320x200 pixels. 
int 10h
```

Normally, CX is only doubled in 320 x 200 pixels graphics mode.
This is also documented in the emu8086 documentation as you can see in the following image:

[image: get mouse position and status of its buttons]